# Is it possible to know from which package a procedure has been called?

Tags: oracle, plsql, stack, package

Suppose that I have 2 packages : A and B.

In package A, I call a procedure in package B.

In procedure of packcage B, is it possible to know that procedure has been called from package A ?

---

Thank you very much for these informations. It was very instructive.

I appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use procedure called `who_called_me` from the Oracle supplied package `OWA_UTIL`

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25221_04/web.1013/b25598/psutil.htm#i1006497

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to parse the text returned by the `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK()` function.

Edit: I tried creating some test packages. I have a procedure in the XX_TESTA package calling another in the XX_TESTB package. The procedure in XX_TESTB simply prints the text returned by `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK()` to output. This is the resulting text:

```
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
416fe0e68         5  package body APPS.XX_TESTB
415182f10         5  package body APPS.XX_TESTA
416e9b448         3  anonymous block
```

Comment: Probably a better suggestion than mine.  I find $$PLSQL_UNIT really useful but I don't think it's that well known because it's relatively new.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the name through as a parameter?

Using....

```
$$PLSQL_UNIT
```

From:  [http://awads.net/wp/2006/08/03/heres-a-quick-way-to-get-the-line-number-in-plsql](http://awads.net/wp/2006/08/03/heres-a-quick-way-to-get-the-line-number-in-plsql/)

```
EDDIE@XE> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg
  2  IS
  3     PROCEDURE my_proc;
  4  END;
  5  /

Package created.

EDDIE@XE> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_pkg
  2  IS
  3     PROCEDURE my_proc
  4     IS
  5     BEGIN
  6        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Line number: ' || $$plsql_line);
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'Unit: '
  8                              || $$plsql_unit
  9                             );
 10     END;
 11  END;
 12  /

Package body created.

EDDIE@XE> exec my_pkg.my_proc;
Line number: 6
Unit: MY_PKG
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. There's many interesting articles! Added into my rss reader :-)