# how to get the information of about database events and actor information

Tags: oracle

I have one table employee which have column status ,Now problem is someone (might be package or triggers) updating the status value. How to get the information about user id and programming unit information.

I have one solution create trigger on the table for update on this table and capture the information about users from following query

Select information about the user ,user machine and session information

```
select  s.sid
    ,   s.username
    ,   s.machine
    ,   s.program
    ,   s.module
    ,   s.event
    ,   s.service_name 
    ,   sh.USER_ID
    ,   sqls.sql_text
from SYS.V_$SESSION s
    ,V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY sh
    ,V$SQL sqls
    ,v$sqlarea sa
    ,v$sqlarea sap
where s.sid=sh.session_id
    and sqls.sql_id=sh.sql_id
    and UPPER(SQLS.SQL_TEXT) like '%UPDATE ABCD%STATUS%6%'
    and S.PREV_SQL_ID = SAP.SQL_ID (+)
    and sqls.sql_id = sa.sql_id (+)
```

but problem is how to get the program unit information which is updating this table ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to know from which package a procedure has been called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773928/is-it-possible-to-know-from-which-package-a-procedure-has-been-called)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `MODULE`, `ACTION` and `CLIENT_INFO` columns of [`V$SESSION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3016.htm).

Then, in the package(s) and/or trigger(s) you suspect are performing the update, call [`DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_appinf.htm#i996826) and `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION`:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(trigger_name, 'trigger start');
  -- some code...
  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('updating employee');
  -- code which updates the employee table
  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('doing something else');
  -- more code...
  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(NULL, NULL);
END;
```

See also the example provided in the [usage notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_appinf.htm#sthref517).